# getItemForm not call second promise

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I have a function that calls the api.send service twice, but when I do the test expecting it to solve the two promises, it only returns the res1, but not res2, how can I solve it?

My function:

```
getItemForm = () => {
              this.api.send('filter', 'get', { lang: 'ES', filter: { id: this.item['id'] } }).then(res1 => {
                this.item = res1['data'][0];
                this.api.send('filter', 'get', { lang: 'EN', filter: { id: this.item['id'] } }).then(res2 => {
                  let itemEng = res2['data'][0];
                });
              });
            };
```

My test:

```
it('should call api.send with res Eng', () => {
            
            component.formDef = [{ field_id: 57, field_key: "name1", field_name: 'test1' }];
            let res1 = { data: [{ id: 1, name: 'test1' }, { id: 2, name: 'test1' }] };
            let res2 = { data: [{ id: 1, name: 'test2' }, { id: 2, name: 'test' }] };
            component.item = let item = {id:1, count: 1, data:[{id: 1, tacticas: {95: [135]}}]};

            let spy1 = spyOn(api, 'send').and.returnValues(Promise.resolve(res1), Promise.resolve(res2));

            component.itemToForm();

            expect(spy1).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(spy1).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly think you should change the implementation of your function. You are not returning anything from it, not sure how are you even getting `res1`. Do something like this:

```
getItemForm = async () => {
              const res1 = await this.api.send('filter', 'get', { lang: 'ES', filter: { id: this.item['id'] } }),
                    res2 = await this.api.send('filter', 'get', { lang: 'EN', filter: { id: this.item['id'] } })     
               return {res1, res2};         
};
```